# In Spring, is it better practice to return a ResponseEntity directly from the service or should i create it inside the controller?

Tags: java, spring

Which of the two options is better practice:

1)

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_BACKOFFICE')")
public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployee(@PathVariable long id) {
  return employeeService.getEmployee(id);
}
```

Service:

```
ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployee(long id) {
  return ResponseEntity.ok(findByEmployeeId(id));
}
```

2)

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_BACKOFFICE')")
public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployee(@PathVariable long id) {
  return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeService.getEmployee(id));
}
```

Service:

```
Employee getEmployee(long id) {
  return findByEmployeeId(id);
}
```

I personally thought 1) is the better option, because some API-requests can return different ResponseEntities. A PUT-request for example could return `ResponseEntity.ok` if the resource exists and was updated. If the resource doesnt exist, it could create it and return `ResponseEntity.created`. By returning that directly in the service im avoiding adding logic to the controller. That way im keeping the controller clean. But in other projects ive seen people using option 2) and i wonder, whats the advantage of that?

Comment: Your service shouldn't be tied to the web. The controller is the layer for adapting the result from your service to something usable for the web. That isn't the responsibility  of the service. What if you want to use the same service method for both a soap webservice or a messaging endpoint?

Comment: See Ports and Adapters approach to design and code organisation from [Clean Architecture](http://www.informit.com/store/clean-architecture-a-craftsmans-guide-to-software-structure-9780134494166), chapter 34.

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 is better, as the service should not be aware of http related things

Comment: But doesnt that add additional logic to the controller in some cases? Like the one example with the PUT-request i wrote above. In a PUT-request after i get the answer from the service inside the controller i would have to somehow check whether the resource was updated or created and then return a different HttpStatus depending on the result. I thought the goal is to avoid logic like that inside the controller.

Comment: It could add logic to the controller, but it is web related logic, which actually belongs to to controller!

Comment: How would you design the PUT request example elegantly? Because the service would return an object of the same type either way, no matter whether he replaced a resource or created a new one. With the returned object being the same type in both situations, how does the controller know whether he has to return status 200 for ok(if replaced) or status 201(if created). Or would the controller have to check whether the resource exists before calling a service method and then call either a service method which replaces or creates a resource? Would that check count as web related logic?

Comment: You can return a wrapper object from the service, with an additional boolen property to tel wether the object was created or replaced